# How to get window.showHide global variable to change contents of a variable in one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a variable const that i can't change the name. i want to be able to do a conditional check and change its value based on the Boolean value of a window.Variable. like code below. any help would be appreciated.

```
const routes = { () => window.showHide  ? routes1 : routes2 }
```

Comment: You don't need the `{}` or the arrow function, it seems like you're after just `const routes = window.showHide ? routes1 : routes2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const routes = window.showHide  ? routes1 : routes2;
```

// Expression of right side is evaluated before it is assigned to const variable

also in fact if you feel you have any context issue or complex logic to have it inline, solve it using iifi

ex:

```
    const routes = (() => {
        let result;
        // Write logic to get final value to assign in const and assign to result, which is retured from iifi function
        return result//
    })();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).